# How to restore and commit previuos version in git?

Tags: git, commit, restore

Lets suppose git log shows versions:

```
fff
...
ccc
bbb
aaa
```

How to get back to version bbb and commit it without destroying history. So that git log would show:

```
bbb*
fff
...
ccc
bbb
aaa
```

Comment: `git reset --hard bbb` is not enough because it destroys history.

Comment: `git checkout bbb` is not enough because it does not commit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to try doing `git revert`:

```
git revert -n  fff eee ddd ccc
```

And of course, you can use notations like `master~4..master` etc.

Comment: I'm looking for an easier way than listing 15 or so commit hashes. I don't like counting the number of commits either. Too easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @Stancell - You can use the notation like I mentioned in the last line.

Comment: Yes, it would work. It would be even better if I could do something like `git revert -n bbb..master`. Suppose every new year I have to bring new year version of web page ar logo. Counting hundreds of commits is not an option :)

Comment: @Stancell - Why don't you do  some research? You can do `bbb..master`. That is why I said `etc.`

Comment: I tried it before responding. `git revert -n 510862f12f857c98ae..master` results in `fatal: Cannot find '510862f12f857c98ae..master'`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Stancell - The sha1 hash must not be proper then. It should work ( and works for me )

Comment: @Stancell: What version of git are you using? The ability to revert sequences of commits was added in 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *could* use `git reset --hard`, if you follow it with a `git reset --soft` back to where you were:

```
git reset --hard bbb
git reset --soft fff
git commit
```